# Protection level changed mid project - now project won't build

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

Started a new SSIS project, and forgot to set the default protection level to "Don't save sensitive" (our standard)  Now midway through the project and made the changes (at project level and in each package.)  When checked all packages are Don't Save Sensitive and the project is Don't Save Sensitive, however when attempting a build, I get

> Project consistency check failed. The following inconsistencies were
>   detected:     PACKAGE1.dtsx has a different ProtectionLevel than the
>   project.  PACKAGE2.dtsx has a different ProtectionLevel than the
>   project.  ...  PACKAGE(N).dtsx has a different ProtectionLevel than
>   the project.

(it lists every package in the project even though they all match the Project level protection.)

Comment: Did you make the change through the GUI or did you edit the dtsx by hand?

Comment: Through the GUI first pass then through by hand, then I started on the .dtproj file, then I had to rebuild to tie it all together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I  suspect you ran into the same issue I did. I corrected all my packages via the API so that they all indicated they were `DTS:ProtectionLevel="0"` which is unprotected.

The project (.dtproj) file also has a protection level which gets set to DontSaveSensitive.  `<SSIS:Project SSIS:ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive" xmlns:SSIS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS">`

The mismatch for me was that inside the project file, it keeps track of far too much information about each package so if you scroll down, you'll see an entry per package like 
`<SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ProtectionLevel">3</SSIS:Property>` or whatever the default number is. Make that `0` in the file (search and replace). Save the project file and it'll now build.

You might need to perform a Build All to get it to build. I suspect that VS/SSDT is trying to use the extra data it stores in the .dtproj file to determine whether it needs to validate all the packages in a project. Since we hand edited the file, it didn't trip whatever sensor would normally be flipped to signal a full recompile was needed.

Comment: Just started down that path...  Still having issues but you are correct.  I will finalize my fix, update with comments here and accept your answer shortly.

Comment: That was it.  Build still failed first time after fixing and checking in, but it was possibly looking at the bin folder for some of the information???  anyway I needed to do a rebuild to get it to succeed.  Having done that Build works properly again.

Comment: Factored the need for a rebuild into the answer along with some guessing on the why.

Answer (score 2):

billinkc's answer didn't work for me because changing the value with a text editor doesn't change it correctly. The following MSDN page explains that there is a cmd line tool to manage this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879310.aspx

Like so:

```
for %f in (*.dtsx) do dtutil.exe /file %f /encrypt file;%f;2;strongpassword
```

It will change every module in the project to the protection level specified in the second to last value. If it is 0, don't store values, then you don't need the password and can get rid of the last semicolon and everything after.

The following MSDN article has a table with the numbers for each protection level, as used with dtutil:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft have broken this so that even using the DTUTIL utility to change package protections doesn't fix the project file metadata.

I had to apply to manual fix to the project file to change metadata storing a copy of the Package Protection level of the packages to the same as that of the project and packages.

Thought through? Probably not.

Get list of packages (that have already been deployed and create DTUTIL statements.  Put them in a batch file and execute from a command line.

**This only works for deployed packages as we are looking at SSISDB and not the Project folder**

```
USE SSISDB
DECLARE @projName VARCHAR(250) = 'Sales'

DECLARE @FolderPath VARCHAR(1000) = 'E:\ssis_' + @projName

DECLARE @DtutilString VARCHAR(1000) =
    '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe"/file "'+ @FolderPath +'\XXX" /encrypt file;"'+ @FolderPath +'\XXX";0 /quiet'

SELECT DISTINCT
       REPLACE(@DtutilString, 'XXX', pack.[name])
--     SELECT *
FROM internal.packages AS pack
    INNER JOIN
        [internal].[projects] AS proj
        ON pack.project_id = proj.project_id

WHERE proj.name = 'ssis_' + @projName
```

Comment: Two things: A) please refrain from using obscenities on this site, and B) this does not attempt to answer the question, it looks more like a rant. If you care to elaborate on how you fixed the project file and how that solved your problem, please do [edit] your post.