# Project consistency check failed. has a different ProtectionLevel than the project

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have this annoying problem where it says that the project and package have different protectionlevels. Which is not true, they are all the same set to "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey".

I tried this [Protection level changed mid project - now project won't build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705161/protection-level-changed-mid-project-now-project-wont-build) and some other solutions, non worked.

Whenever I want to build or rebuild it says:

> Error 1   Project consistency check failed. The following
>   inconsistencies were detected:    Persoon.dtsx has a different
>   ProtectionLevel than the project.     CountableUren.dtsx has a different
>   ProtectionLevel than the project.     Projecten.dtsx has a different
>   ProtectionLevel than the project.     Master_LAB_DSA.dtsx has a different
>   ProtectionLevel than the project.     DimProject.dtsx has a different
>   ProtectionLevel than the project.     DimPersoon.dtsx has a different
>   ProtectionLevel than the project.     DimLookupSources.dtsx has a
>   different ProtectionLevel than the project.   InitializeDim.dtsx has a
>   different ProtectionLevel than the project.   Master_LAB_ETL.dtsx has a
>   different ProtectionLevel than the project.   Master_LAB_DWH.dtsx has a
>   different ProtectionLevel than the project.       0   0

In "View code" there is no "DTS:ProtectionLevel="X"" when set to "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey". And in the project's property, it's set to "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey". I also tried setting everything to "DontSaveSensitive", which also gave me the same error.

How to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post the contents of your .dtproj where the node has `ProtectionLevel` referenced. Something, somewhere is out of whack. Either it's the existing packages or the project file

Comment: How to open the file and see the code? I can only select properties when right clicking the project dtproj

Comment: How to find the node?

Comment: Right click on ProjectName and select Properties. Look in Properties window and find FullPath. Copy that value. Close the existing project/solution. Ctrl-O (open file) and in the resulting Open File dialogue, paste the path to the .dtproj. Ctrl-F and look through all the `ProtectionLevel` items. Numeric value for EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey ought to be 1

Comment: O I thought it would be somewhere else, because in this file there is no ProtectionLevel. I already opened it with notepad++ and bracket and now with Visual Studio. I'll copy paste the code inside dtproj above in my question

Comment: If there's no ProtectionLevel node, then I assume you used the Integration Services Import Project Wizard to create your project from an existing deploy?

Comment: No, I made the project in my other pc, then just used open project and opened the project. I got errors stating that someone else had made the project and it had problems with decrypting xml etc. So I changed the ProtectionLevel of the project and packages to DoNotSave, then received the errors above. Then I changed project protection in it's properties menu to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey and removed all the "DTS:ProtectionLevel="X"" from the all the packages view code. Then every packages was set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey  by itself. But I still get the error that they are not the same

Comment: You included the dtproj.user file Turn off hide file extensions in Windows Explorer. Second line should start with `<Project`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was indeed looking in the wrong user dtproj file. I found out that some of the ProtectionLevel values were 1 and others 2. I changed everything to 0 inside notepad++ saved it, changed the ProtectionLevel inside Visual Studio of the project and all packages to DontSaveSensitive and now I can build and run everything without errors. Thanks. Could you post your answer so I can mark it as answer? Problem was that the ProtectionLevel values were not the same within the project dtproj hidden file.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Solution was found by the help of billinkc in the comments above and by following this solution: [Protection level changed mid project - now project won't build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705161/protection-level-changed-mid-project-now-project-wont-build)

Problem was that the ProtectionLevel's were not the same. Some were 1 and others 2, while in the properties menu they were all the same.

So these steps got it fixed:

1. Open your project in Visual Studio (2012).
2. Right Click your project name in Solution Explorer to the right of
   the screen and select Properties
3. Change ProtectionLevel under Security to *DontSaveSensitive*
4. Double click a package and under Properties, there should be a list
   with properties. Change ProtectionLevel under Security to
   *DontSaveSensitive* in the Properties (do this for all packages)
5. Save all Close Visual Studio (2012)
6. Then go to C:\ProjectName\ProjectName\  And search for the file with
   .dtproj extension. The one with the type **Integration Services
   Project File** and *not* the one with the type *Visual Studio
   Project User Options File*.
7. Open ProjectName.dtproj with a text editor. I used notepad++, but
   you can also open it using Visual Studio, and other text editors.
8. Search for  and change
   *EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey* to *DontSaveSensitive*.
9. Search for  and change
   any number behind this to *0* zero. Search the entire file, there
   should be more than one if you have more packages than one.
10. Save the file, close it, go into Visual Studio (2012) and Right
     Click on the project name in Solution Explorer and click build.
     Everything should work now.

Comment: These instructions also worked (well enough) for the same issue using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Why didn't you simply set *EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey* to 1 in the .dtproj file?

Comment: gaborhodi probably meant 'replace EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey' with 1 in SIS:ProtectionLevel=

Comment: This basically worked for us VS 2017 enterprise.  We set ProtectionLevel from 1 to 0 on all 20+ of the packages that were in this solution.  We found we had to do a Rebuild not just a Build to fix this.   I would be curious why this happens in the first place and why actions taken in the SSIS gui developer don't fix it (you have to manually edit the dtprof file to fix this).

Comment: Further update on VS 2017 Enterprise.   Hit this problem in another solution.   I think it depends on how the solution was constructed.   In this case all I had to do was set at the very highest solution level property DontSaveSensitive (Step 3. above)  and Rebuild the project.   That was all I had to do.   I didn't need to manually edit the xml in each of the individual packages, maybe they were already DontSaveSensitive.

Comment: I tried on VS2019 and it didn't work. I created a new package and copy the flow to another package and delete the old one. It is only one package in my case so it is easy to do.

Answer (score 6):

I received this error with a new dtsx that I'd created in a solution that had others.

I removed the new package and re-added it, and it was fine.

Comment: This is much simpler than the original accepted solution... Worked like a charm...

Comment: @ahmedmzl yeah, but the original answer was 3 years prior to this one.

Comment: Agree this is just some Microsoft mess up.  Nice solution to clear the decks.   But it didn't work for me on a medium sized (10 packages) solution with vs 2019 Pro and git.

Answer (score 0):

Close the Visual Studio

This is for Visual Studio 2019.

Change this for the project causing issue in the `*.dtproj` file

```
<SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ProtectionLevel">0</SSIS:Property>
```

delete the .vs/ bin/ and obj/ folders

Then rebuild your solution